# Why VBA code works with F8 but not when run F5

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

VBA code works with F8 but not when run F5. Help!

I even tried Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03") but it still does not work.

It does not give error mesagges. The first worksheet works perfect but from the second worksheet it shows 0 as results instead of the right values

Any suggestions?

Here is the code:

```
Sub edittrinvoice() ' Dim ws As Worksheet Dim i As Integer

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

ws.Name = ws.Cells(2, 28).Value & "-e"
ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = ws.Cells(2, 28).Value

ws.Columns("AD:AH").EntireColumn.Delete
ws.Columns("U:AB").EntireColumn.Delete
ws.Columns("R:S").EntireColumn.Delete
ws.Columns("C:P").EntireColumn.Delete

ws.Columns("A:H").ColumnWidth = 11

ws.Rows("2:17").EntireRow.Delete


ws.Pictures.Delete

ws.Cells.UnMerge
ws.Cells.Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
ws.Cells.Font.Name = "calibri"
ws.Cells.Font.Size = 10
ws.Cells.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignTop

ws.Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
ws.Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
ws.Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight


ws.Columns("H:H").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
ws.Columns("H:H").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
ws.Columns("H:H").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
ws.Columns("H:H").Insert Shift:=xlToRight


Application.DisplayAlerts = False


ws.Columns("C:C").TextToColumns Destination:=ws.Cells(1, 3), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

ws.Columns("G:G").TextToColumns Destination:=ws.Cells(1, 7), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

ws.Columns("L:L").TextToColumns Destination:=ws.Cells(1, 12), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

i = 1 
For i = 1 To 100 
If ws.Cells(i, 3) <> 0 Then 
ws.Cells(i, 5) = Cells(i, 3) + Cells(i, 4) / 100 
ws.Cells(i, 9) = Cells(i, 7) + Cells(i, 8) / 100 
ws.Cells(i, 14) = Cells(i, 12) + Cells(i, 13) / 100 
End If 
Next i


ws.Columns("J:M").EntireColumn.Delete
ws.Columns("F:H").EntireColumn.Delete
ws.Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Delete

>> i tried to add wait here but it does not work so I removed it
' Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03")

Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your loop. You have dutifully used a parent worksheet reference everywhere but the maths operation in your loop.

You have,

```
For i = 1 To 100 
  If ws.Cells(i, 3) <> 0 Then 
    ws.Cells(i, 5) = Cells(i, 3) + Cells(i, 4) / 100 
    ws.Cells(i, 9) = Cells(i, 7) + Cells(i, 8) / 100 
    ws.Cells(i, 14) = Cells(i, 12) + Cells(i, 13) / 100 
  End If 
Next i
```

Should be,

```
For i = 1 To 100 
  If ws.Cells(i, 3) <> 0 Then 
    ws.Cells(i, 5) = ws.Cells(i, 3) + ws.Cells(i, 4) / 100 
    ws.Cells(i, 9) = ws.Cells(i, 7) + ws.Cells(i, 8) / 100 
    ws.Cells(i, 14) = ws.Cells(i, 12) + ws.Cells(i, 13) / 100 
  End If 
Next i
```

You might also want to consider a `With/End With` block.

```
With ws
  For i = 1 To 100 
    If .Cells(i, 3) <> 0 Then 
      .Cells(i, 5) = .Cells(i, 3) + .Cells(i, 4) / 100 
      .Cells(i, 9) = .Cells(i, 7) + .Cells(i, 8) / 100 
      .Cells(i, 14) = .Cells(i, 12) + .Cells(i, 13) / 100 
    End If 
  Next i
End With
```

Of course, that `With/End With` method could actually be applied to everything inside the larger worksheet loop.

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  With ws

    'all ws.Cells are now referred to as .Cells (note the . in .Cells)

  End With
Next ws
```